# Infinite yield problem

Tags: python, generator

Here is my simple code

```
class Fibonacci:
    @staticmethod
    def series():
        fprev = 1
        fnext = 1
        yield fnext
        while True:
            yield fnext
            fprev,fnext = fnext,fprev+fnext

under10 = (i for i in Fibonacci.series() if i<10)
for i in under10 :
    print i
```

It's absolutely obvious, but...WHY interpreter is executing block

```
while True:
                yield fnext
                fprev,fnext = fnext,fprev+fnext
```

Forever?
I specified in generator,that I want only elements<10

```
under10 = (i for i in Fibonacci.series() if i<10)
```

IMHO, it's a little bit misunderstanding
Any way to prevent infinite execution without re-writing "series"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How should the interpreter know that all future numbers will be < 10? It would have to either *know* (somehow) that it’s churning out the Fibonacci series, or it would have to inspect the whole series.

It can’t do the first, so it does the second.

You can fix this by using [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
import itertools

under10 = itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n < 10, Fibonacci.series())
```

Comment: @phimuemue: agreed, takewhile is a must if you use generators

Comment: Thanks,Konrad. That's what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
under10 = (i for i in Fibonacci.series() if i<10)
```

Will keep going, it just won't yield values greater than 10.  There's nothing instructing the for loop to stop.

You would probably have better luck doing something like:

```
for i in Fibonacci.series():
    if i > 10:
        break
    #do your appends and such here
```

EDIT:

I like Konrad's itertools example much more, I always forget about itertools

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop isn't a result of the `while True:` in the `Fibonacci.series()` method. It's caused by the `under10 = (i for i in Fibonacci.series() if i<10)` generator which just keeps going since it doesn't realize the values yielded will never get smaller. Here's [another] way to fix it *and generalize it* at the same time -- without re-writing `series()` -- using the `itertools.takewhile()` iterator:

```
import itertools
fibos_under = lambda N: itertools.takewhile(lambda f: f < N, Fibonacci.series())

for i in fibos_under(10):
    print i
```

**BTW:** You can simplify the `Fibonacci.series()` method slightly by changing it to this which yields the same values:

```
class Fibonacci:
    @staticmethod
    def series():
        fprev,fnext = 0,1
        while True:
            yield fnext
            fprev,fnext = fnext,fprev+fnext
```